# Excel, Create a table, Reference cell, Start Date, End Date

Tags: excel, create-table

I just want to create a table by reference of two cells. One of them will be start date and other one will be end date.

I want to create a table that has a reference to these two cells. If the start date is May 6 and the end date is May 11 then the table will automatically add necessary columns, for this 1st column of the table has May 6 date and the last column of the table has the May 11 date.

Also, if I change the start date and end date, the table should adjust by itself by adding or removing columns depending on the last date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `5-May-2022` in cell <kbd>**A1**</kbd> and `11-May-2022` in cell <kbd>**B1**</kbd>. Then use below `SEQUENCE()` function-

```
=SEQUENCE(1,(B1-A1)+1,A1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What if I change end date to May 22, that will be change automatically. I mean it will start adding in H4, I4, J4 ...... automatically

Comment: @user19867963 Yes, that will generate dates till end date automatically.